# use of undeclared crate or module, "use crate_name::schema::posts" doesn't always work

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to learn Rust by using it with `actix-web` and `diesel`.

When I try to import/use the schema by using the crate name it only works in the `example.rs` file but not in the `post.rs` file. Both files are nested in their own folders and the command I'm using is the following:

`use web_project_core::schema::posts;`

When I use this other command instead, it works in `post.rs` but not in `example.rs`:

`use super::super::schema::posts;`

What am I missing?

```rust
// Cargo.toml
[lib]
name = "web_project_core"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

```rust
// main.rs

use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

mod handlers;
```

```rust
// lib.rs
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
extern crate dotenv;

use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

pub mod schema;
pub mod modelz;
```

```rust
// post.rs

use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use nanoid::generate;

use super::super::schema::posts;        // <-- it works
// use web_project_core::schema::posts; // <-- it doesn't work
```

```
// example.rs

use actix_web::{get, web, post, HttpResponse, Responder};
use diesel::prelude::*;

use web_project_core::establish_connection;
use web_project_core::schema::posts;            // <-- it works
// use super::super::schema::posts;             // <-- it doesn't work
use web_project_core::modelz::post::*;
```

The project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between `example.rs` and `post.rs` is that `post.rs` is in the library crate `web_project_core` while `example.rs` is in the binary crate `main`.
The path `web_project_core::schema::posts` is not available in `post.rs` as `web_project_core` is the current crate, rather than a dependency.
Instead of `web_project_core::schema::posts` you could use `crate::schema::posts`, when referring to the current crate. The binary implicitly depends on the library as they are in the same package, making the path `web_project_core::schema::posts` available in `example.rs`